# Xcode - Unable to enable App Groups from second app

Tags: ios, xcode9, appgroups

I'm trying to create an App Group for sharing data between two apps.  In one app, I've created and successfully accessed the App Group.

However, when I go to the other app and attempt to enable the app group, I get a whole bunch of errors relating the certificate and entitlements files.

The group shows up in my App Groups Capabilities area:
[image]

But when I click on it, a second copy of the group appears and errors appear all over my capabilities tabs :
[image]

and code signing area:

[image]

I've already tried deleting derived data, clean and build, etc.  Hoping to avoid managing the provisioning profile manually.

Comment: "Hoping to avoid managing the provisioning profile manually." I don't see why, and I don't think you can avoid it. There is a [known bug](https://github.com/lionheart/openradar-mirror/issues/16702) where automatic profile management doesn't work correctly with app group entitlements, and I think you've just hit that bug. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try a different provisional profile for the second app.